# Run Time Push notification to native android application using Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, api, push-notification

as far as i know we can use Signalr and jquery you use the push
the run time notification inside of the asp.net framework but that is with the help of "jquery" so the signalr only support webpages of run time notification 
so what if i wanted to send a run time notification from a asp.net web api to an android device written in java or so ? 
is there any thing or a starting point to begin with?

Comment: Here is the starting point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SignalR already has client [SDK for Android](https://github.com/SignalR/java--client).
- If you want to build a chat application, you need concern about some special case such as user not using client/mobile app at the send notification time or they use many different devices and so on.
- If you just want to build "push notification" feature for your mobile app like a marketing campaign or an announce to users, it should better you push notification via [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1001467%20%7C%20Firebase*%20Brand%20Features%20%7C%20Global%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20Desk%2BTab%2BMobile%20%7C%20Text%20%7C%20BKWS%20%5B2017%5D&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsq6Cr-_j1gIVCyS9Ch0p9wkdEAAYASAAEgJ3DfD_BwE) for Android app and [apple cloud](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) for iOS app.

  - Some C# framework support push notification for many platforms.I usually use 
    [One Signal](https://onesignal.com) because it free at all and easy to integration with.